# injective functions

Tags: functions

If $f(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ are both injections, does it follow that $g(x)$ is an injection? Explain your answer.

I'm having trouble with this question. I understand what the definition of an injective function is, but I'm not sure how to work this problem out in my head. Also, if you have the time, the study guide I'm looking at asks the exact same question but with SURJECTION juxtaposed for INJECTION. some explanation on that as well would be nice. thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Write out the definitions of what it means to be an injection (resp surjection).

Answer (score 1):

Take any two $x, y$ such that $g(x) = g(y)$. If you can prove that $x=y$, then $g$ is injective.

**Hint:** Because $g(x) = g(y)$, it is clear that $f(g(x)) = f(g(y)).$